# Use of constexpr function before definition fails

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

I'm having some trouble with `constexpr`. The book *C++ Primer* shows a line of code:

```
  constexpr int sz = size(); // only size() is a constexpr function
                             // this code is right
```

However the book doesn't give a specific example. So I try the following code by myself:

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr int fun();
int main()
{
    constexpr int f = fun();
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
constexpr int fun()
{
    return 3;
}
```

But [clang 3.4.1 says](https://godbolt.org/z/v7W5bd4nj):

> undefined function 'fun' cannot be used in a constant expression

If I change `constexpr` into `const`, it works well, and if I change my code to define the constexpr function before use:

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr int fun()
{
    return 3;
}
int main()
{
    constexpr int f = fun();
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
```

It also works well. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `constexpr` function does NOT have to be defined before its first use, however the result of any call made prior to definition is not a constant expression.

Source: C++ Standard draft n4296, section 5.20:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`,  except  in  a  `constexpr`  function  or  a  `constexpr` constructor  that  is  being  evaluated  as part of `e`;
> - an invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class, a `constexpr` function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor [ Note:  Overload resolution is applied as
>     usual  — end note ];
> - **an  invocation  of  an  undefined `constexpr`  function**  or  an  undefined  `constexpr`  constructor;
> - ...

version from draft 3485 (section 5.19):

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated  subexpression,  but  subexpressions  of  logical  AND,  logical  OR,  and  conditional operations that are not evaluated are not considered [ Note:  An overloaded operator invokes a function. — end note ]:
>
> - `this` [ Note:  when evaluating a constant expression,  function invocation substitution replaces each occurrence of  `this` in a `constexpr` member function with a pointer to the class object. — end note ];
> - an  invocation  of  a  function  other  than  a  `constexpr`  constructor  for  a  literal  class  or  a  `constexpr` function [ Note:  Overload resolution is applied as usual  — end note ];
> - **an invocation of an undefined `constexpr` function** or an undefined `constexpr` constructor
> - ...

The example `int x2 = s. t();` in n2235 actually became valid due to the changes made prior to Standardization.  However, `constexpr int x2 = s. t();` remains an error.

Comment: n4296 is a draft C++ Standart. Did compilers already support it?

Comment: @kvorobiev: I'm quoting from a draft because it is public.  The rule was introduced quite a few drafts earlier, and is part of the official Standard.

Comment: @kvorobiev you can look at N3337 5.19/2, which is basically the final version of the C++11 standard. g++/clang++ are C++11 compliant (with minor exceptions)

Comment: Included another version.  As you can see, the definition of *core constant expression* has changed a fair bit, but this particular bullet point hasn't.

Comment: Can you explain _why_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because a declaration contains everything the compiler needs to generate code for a function call, but only the definition provides everything needed to actually perform the calculation in the compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That still doesn't in itself explain why the definition needs to already have been seen, lexically. I imagine the phrase "single pass" comes into the answer somehow :)

Comment: @lightness C++ compilers are not single pass, though. The restriction is still valuable in preventing circular type dependencies, however.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The reason I ask is that someone posted a near-duplicate of this question yesterday, but felt that these answers don't amply explain the rationale behind the standard wording. I was hoping we could beef them up a little in that regard. :)

Answer (score 3):

A constant expression function must be defined before its first use. See this [paper](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf), end of section 4.1.

Comment: So then the book is in error?  Perhaps some compilers accept this syntax despite not being allowed by the standard?

Comment: According to this [table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) few compilers support constexpr now and I doubt that one of them supports this syntax.

Comment: @kvorobiev but the most important compilers are quite C++11-ready, in particular g++/clang++. MSVC not yet, but getting there.