# Forward-declaration of a `constexpr` function inside another function -- Compiler bug?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, function-declaration, compiler-bug

While producing a MCVE for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37526366/3233393) problem I stumbled upon, I've found the following discrepancy between compilers:

Consider the following code :

```
// constexpr int f(); // 1

constexpr int g() {
    constexpr int f(); // 2
    return f();
}

constexpr int f() {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int i = g();
    return i;
}
```

This code compiles on Clang 3.8.0, but fails on GCC 6.1.0 with:

```
error: 'constexpr int f()' used before its definition
```

Commenting out `// 2` and uncommenting `// 1` works on both compilers.

Interestingly, moving `f`'s definition in place of `// 1` compiles, but triggers a warning at `// 2`:

```
warning: inline function 'constexpr int f()' used but never defined
```

Which compiler is right ?

Comment: Standard doesn't seem to be quite clear on this. We need a strong lawyer here :)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the `constexpr` functions with `inline` functions retains the exact same problem (it is okay with the global declaration 1, but not with the function-scope declaration 2.) Since `constexpr` implies `inline` this seems like the cause.

In this case, with declaration 2, GCC complains:
`warning: 'inline' specifier invalid for function 'f' declared out of global scope`
and `warning: inline function 'int f()' used but never defined`.
It fails to link ("`undefined reference to 'f()'`").

So it looks like it gives up on inlining, puts in a call, but doesn't bother emitting code for `f()` because all uses are inlined (?), so the link fails.

and Clang complains:
`error: inline declaration of 'f' not allowed in block scope`

Since `constexpr` implies `inline`, it seems that this rule that inline declarations are not allowed in block scope should also apply to `constexpr`, and so GCC is correct. But the standard does not seem to come out and say this. In the draft I examined, the rule about `inline` is in §7.1.2 [dcl.fct.spec], part 3: "The inline specifier shall not appear on a block scope function declaration", but nothing similar appears about `constexpr`.